# changing a control label to a button to access my terms & conditions page in Razor Views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I need to change this label to a button to link to my Terms & Conditions page on my site. Right now it is a label and checks the AGREE box next to it
to show that the user has agreed to terms. I would like it to be a button that 
displayed the terms and then give the ability to check the AGREE box next to the label if the person agrees with terms. I'm new to Razor Views and I'm
not sure how to proceed.

Thanks

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgreedToTerms, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgreedToTerms)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgreedToTerms)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect to another page to show the terms and conditions, or display then in a popup on the same page or have then on the page but initially hidden? (unclear why the terms are not just displayed above the checkbox)

Comment: The terms and conditions are based on company rules and are very lengthy think EULA type length. I want to display my Terms.cshtml view and then after the user reads the terms it will go back to prior page and give them option to opt in in a Boolean field that gets compared and rights are given then

Comment: Then you need a link to redirect to that page (but why not just show it in the existing page (make it hidden initially if you want and then click on a link/button to toddle its visibility)

Answer (score 0):

A button might be less ideal for MVC and routing to another page, I suggest an action link.

Try using an `@Html.ActionLink`, pass the name of the action and controller that handles that action to it, which can send a user to the AgreedToTerms page.

Comment: How would that code look? I would have to put the Terms first as the action and the Home as the controller in the action link right? What would the user click on to

Comment: To get to the terms page from above sorry ran out of edit time on this POS constructed sight

Comment: And how can I get it on the same line as the acknowledgement box and the link itself ?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("ActionLinkText", "Index");`, would be one way, or to include the controller to use,
 
`@Html.ActionLink("ActionLinkName", "Index", "Home");`

 where the Index would be the Action, and this would use the Home controller. ActionLink has a couple overrides that is usable, route values can also be set, so if you wanted to pass a value from a textbox to the controller, you can use route values parameter.

The html would be something like the following:

`<a href="/">ActionLinkName</a`

The user would click on a link.

Comment: The terms page would use a terms page, with a terms controller. I would image the code looking like,

`@Html.ActionLink("Terms Page", "Index", "Terms")`